# Which word is more correct to use in this case?

Tags: difference

"If you are ... with this test, perhaps you should attempt an easier one".
Why is it more correct to use "struggling" instead of "straining" in this sentence?

I guess, that the verb "struggle" is used more to refer to fighting.

Comment: **Struggling with [something]** is a common expression which means *having trouble/problems/difficulties with something*.  The use of *struggling* here is figurative, not a literal fight/violent act.  It is the correct verb to use  in this context.

Comment: **Straining** refers to a physical effort. "He was straining to lift the heavy box."

Answer (score 1):

That's just the meanings of he words.  "Struggle" suggests "make an attempt, without success".  Strain means experience pressure or stretch.

You might say that the test is straining you. I suppose you could say "I was straining my brain" (though that is not really idiomatic).  But "I was straining with this test" just doesn't make sense according to the meanings of the words. The right word to use is struggle.